# PHP preg_match returning the wrong indexes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract all the indexes of a specific word from a string using PHP's `preg_match`. Take for example the word `hello`:

```
$r = "/\b(hello)\b/u";
```

Let's say I want to look for it in this string:

```
$s = 'hello. how are you, hello there. helloorona!';
```

If I run `preg_match` with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` parameter and passing in an array called $matches,

```
preg_match($r, $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I expect something like this to be returned (i.e. ignoring the last "hellooroona" phrase):

```
["hello", 0], ["hello", 20]
```

but in fact, when I return echo the value of `$matches` either through `json_encode` or by looping over all the matches, the value returned is always:

```
["hello", 0], ["hello", 0]
```

If I run this on a similar string, let's say

```
$s = 'how are you, hello there.';
```

the answer is

```
["hello", 13]
```

which is correct. Run it on `hello hello hello` and I get three indexes, all 0.

**Summary**

So it seems like the index counter is simply always returning the first index. Is this expected behavior? How do I get the actual indexes?

Comment: the last hello isn't showing because you are using `\b` which is word boundary eg anything before/after that isn't a word character it will capture it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `["hello", 0]` is not the second hello in your string, but the match of sub group.

Use `preg_match_all` which will give you the expected result:

```
// note: sub group is not necessary
$r = "/\bhello\b/u";
$s = 'hello. how are you, hello there. helloorona!';
preg_match_all($r, $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I tried using `preg_match_all` but also didn't get what I was expecting - removing the sub group is what solved it in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match` matches *the first* match and then stops. The result array always contains the *entire matched expression* in its `0` index and all *capture groups* in the following indices starting at `1`. E.g.:

```
preg_match('/foo (\w+)/', 'foo bar', $r)
```

`$r` here contains `0 => 'foo bar', 1 => 'bar'`.

So in your case you're just seeing the very first `hello` twice due to this.

If you want to match *all* occurrences of the expression, use `preg_match_all`.